Finding the height of a triangle given base, opposite angle, and position of the height.
This is a real life problem where I need to make a triangle ABC with the given requirements:

The base (AC) is 24cm.
The opposite angle (B) is 170°.
The height (h) is 10cm into AC from A.

That is, there are only two knowns: one angle (B) and one side length (AC). However, the height is fixed to a horizontal dimension.

I want to solve for the unknowns, especially the height h.
Usually three knowns are needed to solve for the rest of this triangle. However I find it hard to create two different triangles that meet the same constraints.
For example, let's create a figure A'B'C'. It follows the same restrictions as triangle ABC but angle A' is 2° bigger than angle A.
Line A'B' and h' are thus slightly longer than line AB and height h so that angle B' and h' still meet. Keeping the same angle of 170°, line B'C' can no longer meet the base 24cm from A.

Similar logic applies if you increase or decrease angles A' or C' by arbitrarily many degrees.
Thus there should be unique angles A and C for any triangle that meets the conditions. And if there are unique angles then by SAA and ASA congruence, there can only be one such triangle (well, one congruence class).
And if there is only one such triangle then there is only one answer.
Of course, this last argument is no formal proof, just intuition. I don't actually know if this is solvable or not.
Here is my attempt anyways, I try to solve for h here:
Let $\theta$ be the angle formed between A, B, and the the intersection of the height and the base. Let $\phi$ be the angle between C,B, and the same intersection.

$\tan(\theta)=\frac{10}{h}$
$\tan(\phi)=\frac{14}{h}$
$h=\frac{10}{\tan(\theta)}=\frac{14}{\tan(\phi)}$

From here I get stuck. Perhaps I can use the tangent angle difference identity to put get rid of one unknown as $\tan(\phi)=\tan(170-\theta)$ or something, but this route doesn't seem obvious either.

Definitely solvable. On given base AC construct the circle subtending 170 and measure 10 inwards, draw the altitude there, that’s the triangle in question.

Sufficient to calculate the left corner angle.  Denote this as $~\theta.$  From the problem's illustration, it is then sufficient to solve for $~\tan(\theta).$
$$ \tan(\theta) = \frac{h}{10}, ~\tan(10^\circ - \theta) = \frac{h}{14} \implies $$
$$10\tan(\theta) = 14 \tan(10^\circ - \theta).\tag1 $$
Also,
$$\tan(10^\circ - \theta) = \frac{\tan(10^\circ) - \tan(\theta)}{1 + \tan(10^\circ)\tan(\theta)}. \tag2 $$
Therefore,
$$10\tan(\theta) ~[ ~1 + \tan(10^\circ)\tan(\theta) ~] = 14 [ ~\tan(10^\circ) - \tan(\theta) ~]. \tag3 $$
(3) above represents a quadratic equation in $~\tan(\theta),~$ where $~\tan(10^\circ)~$ is a known constant.
Let $~P~$ denote the constant $~\tan(10^\circ),~$ and let $~w~$ denote the variable $~\tan(\theta).~$  So, you want to solve for $~w~$ in terms of the constant $~P.~$  Using (3) above, you have that
$$10w(1 + Pw) = 14(P - w) \implies $$
$$w^2(10P) + w(24) + (-14P) = 0 \implies $$
$$w^2(5P) + w(12) + (-7P) = 0. $$
Keeping in mind that $~0 < w = \tan(\theta),~$ this implies that
$$w = \frac{1}{10P} ~\left[ -12 + \sqrt{ ~144 + 140P^2 ~} ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{1}{5P} ~\left[ -6 + \sqrt{36 + 35P^2} ~\right]. \tag4 $$
(4) above, which (in effect) expresses $~\tan(\theta)~$ in terms of $~\tan(10^\circ)~$ may be regarded as the final answer.
Using a calculator, the approximate value of $~\tan(\theta)~$ is $~0.10209,~$ and the approximate value of $~\theta~$ is $~5.82922^\circ.$

This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

First you need to find the circle that includes a center angle with 20 degrees. Drawing the circle is straightforward by creating an isosceles triangle with 80 degrees base. This allow an arc of 170 degrees of the 24 segment. I assume that the following diagram is clear:

Next you place a vertical line through the 10/14 split point. And in the following screen shot you see the segment DF to be 1.02


I see how you constructed it and will definitely use this. Out of curiosity, is there a way, without direct measurement, to precisely calculate the height  DF or angles A and B?

This structure allows you to develop the equations to solve this accurately.
